# Slick 3 batch Update

Tags: postgresql, scala, playframework, slick, slick-3.0

My requirement is to do a batch update to a table. I was able to do a Batch insert but could not find a way to do the batch update in Slick3. Any sample or link to a document will be very help full. Tried to search the web could not find a solution. Using Slick 3 on Postgresql.

Comment: May be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35001493/slick-3-0-bulk-insert-or-update

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just add whatever data you need to perform to a seq and perform the query. That will do the batching for you. [Link here](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.0.0/queries.html#inserting) . This applies to all operations not only insert.

Look at this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24878554/scala-slick-2-0-updateall-equivalent-to-insertall) question to fall back on standard JDBC and do the update batching.
Also there are some items the team is working on. See [here](https://github.com/slick/slick/issues/583).

Comment: Thank you Som. But I am not proficient in this area so it would be very helpful if you can pointy out an example instead of the document.

Comment: okay can you update the question with the code of what you are doing right now ? I will update you with an example.